# Need an advice about algorithm to solve quite specific Job Shop Scheduling Problem

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

Job Shop Scheduling Problem (JSSP): I have jobs that consist of tasks and I have machines  that can perform these tasks.

I should be able to add new jobs dynamically. E.g. I have a schedule for the first 5 jobs, and when the 6th arrive - I need to be able to fit it into the schedule in the best way. It is possible to adjust existing schedule within the given flexibility constrains.

Look at the picture below.

Jobs have tasks, each task is the same type of action. Think about painting of some objects with paint spray. All the machines are the same (paint sprays), and all of the tasks are the same.

Constraint 1. Jobs have a preferred deadline for completion, but the deadline is flexible to some extent.

Edit after @tucuxi answer: Flexible deadline mean that the time of completion can be extended by some delta if necessary.

Constraint 2. Between the jobs there is resting phase. Think about drying the paint. Resting phase has minimal required duration. Resting phase can be longer or shorter if necessary.

Edit after @tucuxi answer: So there is planned time of rest *Tp* which is desired, but flexible value that can be increased or decreased if this allows for better scheduling. And there is minimal time of rest *Tm*. So *Tp-Tadjustmenet>=Tm*.

The machine is occupied by the job from the start to the completion.

**Here goes parts that make this problem very distinct from what I have read about.**

Jobs arrive in batches of several jobs. For example a batch can contain 10 jobs of the type Job_1 and 5 of Job_2. Different batches can contain different types of jobs. All the jobs from the batches should be finished as close to each other as possible. Not necessary at the same time, but we need to minimize the delay between the completion of first and last jobs from the batch.

Constraint 3. Machines are grouped. In each group only *M* machines can work simultaneously. Think about paint sprays that are connected to the common pressurizer that has limited performance.

[image: Simplified diagram to help the reader]

**The goal.**
Having given description of the problem, it should be possible to solve JSSP. It should be also possible to add new jobs to the existing schedule.

Edit after @tucuxi answer: This is not a task that should be solved immediately: it is not a time-critical system. But it shouldn't be too long to irritate a human who put new tasks into the algorithm.

**Question**
What kind of many JSSP algorithms can help me solve this? I can implement an algorithm by myself, if there is one. The closest I found is [This](https://www.localsolver.com/docs/last/exampletour/resource-constrained-project-scheduling-problem-rcpsp.html) - Resource Constrained Project Scheduling Problem. But I was not able to comprehend how can I glue it to the JSSP solving algorithm.

Edit after @tucuxianswer: No, I haven't tried it yet.

Is there any libraries that can be used to solve this problem? Python or C# are the preferred languages, but in the end it doesn't really matter.

I appreciate any help: keyword to search for, link, reference to a book, reference to a library.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is a pre-made algorithm that solves your exact problem.

If I had to solve it, I would first:

- compile datasets of inputs that I can feed into candidate solvers.
- think of a metric to rank outputs, so that I can compare the candidates to see which is better.

A baseline solver could be a brute-force search: test and rate all possible job schedulings for small sample problems. This is of course infeasible for large inputs, but for small inputs it allows you to compare the outputs of more efficient solvers to a known-best answer.

Your link is to *localsolver.com*, which appears to provide a library for specifying problem constraints to then solve them. It is not freely available, requiring a license to use; but it would seem that your problem can be readily modeled in it. Have you tried to do so? They appear to support both C++ and Python. Other free options exist, including optaplanner (2.8k stars in github) or python-constraint (I have not looked into other languages).

Note that a good metric is crucial to choosing a good algorithm: unless you have a clear cost function to minimize, choosing "a good algorithm" is impossible. In your description of the problem, I see several places where cost is unclear (marked in italics):

- job deadlines are *flexible*
- minimal required rest times... which *may be shortened*
- jobs from a batch *should* be finished as close together *as possible*
- (not from specification): how long can you wait for an optimal vs a less-optimal-but-faster solution?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited the question to make it more precise. I was hoping I might be missing something, and there's already a good tool to solve this problem. I totally agree with you comment on metric. The challenge is that in existing libraries it is not always clear how to add complex metrics and constraints.